# How Do I Free Up Disk Space to Install Centos 8?

Tags: centos, cpanel

I just purchased a Linux VPS thinking it came with Centos 8 but to my horror it does not appear to be installed. If I am to make use of this server I need cPanel or I can't use it all because my only experience with Linux servers is with cPanel.

When I try to install Centos it says that the hard drive has zero free bytes. Is this a permissions problem or is the disk corrupt?

Comment: Usually it is done via the providers web interface... I think you should ask your provider...

Comment: There are other control panels besides cPanel. For example, VestaCP is fairly intuitive and their site has a neat feature where it'll generate the install commands to suit your needs.

Comment: The VPSes I am familiar with wouldn't allow you to install a different OS. I suggest asking the host to change the OS for you; they may say that this isn't an option in which case you'd need to find another VPS provider or use the other OS.